# MYSQL: Filter with multiple dates and date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 dates to be filtered by 2 dates.

I have this data on my table

```
id  date_from    date_to     name
1   2018-10-11   2018-10-25  LeBron James
2   2018-10-11   2018-10-25  Stephen Curry
3   2018-10-26   2018-11-10  Kevin Durant
```

What I wanted to do is to filter it base on the date range given.
So If I have the 2 dates(2018-10-01 to 2018-10-22). I will only see id 1 and 2, and if I have (2018-10-12 to 2018-10-31) I will show all data.

My sample code
I used start and end for the range

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date_from BETWEEN @start AND @end) OR (date_to BETWEEN @start AND @end)
```

//
The problem with this is that if no value found in range it will show me everything.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE (date_from >= @start AND date_from <= @end) AND (date_to >= @start AND date_to <= @end)
```

//
The problem - No data will appear

What should I do, I am confused with lots of dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want and overlap.  If so:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table
WHERE t.date_from <= @end AND
      t.date_to >= @start;
```

Two periods overlap if one starts before the second ends and vice versa.

Comment: What magic, It works. Thank you so much sir, and a happy holidays to you

Answer (score 3):

This might help clarify:

```
  @start    @end
s-E |        |        ignore (starts & ends before the period)

 s--|--------|-E      spans the period
  s-|---E    |        start before, but ends in, the period
    s----E   |        starts at beginning of the period, finishes before the period ends
    | s---E  |        starts and finished within the period
    |   s----E        starts within the period, finishes on last day of the period
    |     s--|-E      starts within the period but finishes after the period

    |        | s-E    ignore (starts & ends after the period)

 for those we want s is always <= @end
 for those we want E is always >= @start
```

It can seem counter-intuitive to compare starts to an end point or vice-versa, but as that small graphic attempt to display, it is the most consistent relationship.

Comment: thank you for the clarification sir! happy holidays :)